# Suggest me best solutions to edit /update one billion records in SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am having question, we have to handle huge volume of data, like one billion records that should load into a SharePoint list, after loading into the SharePoint list users can edit and update records.

Suggest me best solutions to edit /update one billion records in SharePoint list

Thanks
Ramesh Reddy

Comment: 1 billion records in a sharepoint list? do me a favour!

Answer (score 6):

1,000,000,000 records? Good luck with that! You may want to revisit the decision to use SharePoint lists as the underlying data store and look at a database instead with some very well constructed indexes.

In case our a masochist though :-

- [Working with Large Lists in Office SharePoint Server 2007](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=95450&clcid=0x409)

Answer (score 3):

If its 2010, BCS could be used, and its available in all versions of SharePoint, completely agree with all the others though, you need to rethink your approach, sounds like you need to leverage a proper DB. If you do need to surface the data in SharePoint BCS and External Content Types in 2010 are a god-send.

Answer (score 1):

A SharePoint list is the wrong storage choice here. A quick quote from the Working with Large Lists in Office SharePoint Server 2007 (bottom of the first paragraph under "Test results and findings"):

> The maximum number of items supported
>   in a list with recursive folders is 5
>   million items.

Perhaps this list is more logically several lists dumped into one?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to expose data through SharePoint, use a regular DB and maybe read about SharePoint Business Data Catalog?

Comment: is BDC a feature of WSS or of MOSS?